# Icon for this site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How are icons for sites on SE defined? I.e., Math.SE, TeX.SE, Unix.SE, and several other of the sites I visit around here have their own, distinctive icons. Others have a just a light blue blurb with white letters (like this one).

If this is up to the community to define, how would we go about defining an icon?

Answer (score 4):

The design we have is the standard beta-site design. Sites get their own design once they "graduate" that is once they leave beta.

It is done by SE staff (possibly/presumably with some community input/feed-back).

I do not think it is possible to get our own design before graduation.

Comment: Note that there is one tiny design aspect that is individual: The content of the speech bubble in our favicon. See [aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) or [chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) for non-acronym examples.